# bash create another shell interface

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

in a bash script, inserting an & will create a child process in which to run the command.
Is it possible to run a gnome-shell, or other windowed interface, in which to run a command?

Comment: From what I see from the tour of the _gnome shell_ project (I have never heard about it before), It does not look like a shell in the sense of bash or sh, but of a program used interactively to do automation. It seems that you can [program new tasks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions) using JavaScript.

Comment: BTW, I took the liberty to change the  tags of your question to match better what you are going to ask.